# rxjs-5-to-6 "Cannot find any possible migrations"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a project that I am trying to upgrade from Angular6 to Angular7.
I have followed Angulars guide for advanced projects when going from 6.1 to 7.1.
https://update.angular.io/

After getting rxjs-tslint ready it will not find any possible migrations.
[rxjs-5-to-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpuXW.png)

I think this is resulting in a problem when I eventually run "ng update --save @angular/cli @angular/core.
[updating starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB0lW.png)
As shown in the picture the packages starts updating.

Then this follows:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3R3.png)
Have I missed anything or is it a migration issue?

Comment: according to errors your bootstrap.css is not found.

Comment: None of these errors were an issue in the Angular6 version. As why I am contemplating there is an issue with the merge.
Does bootstrap.css get removed during upgrade?